# How to download Nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I opened "manage nuget packages for solution" - "browse" - and found what I was looking for. When I clicked on it I got "Installed: not installed". But I can't find how to install it. I already tried right clicking etc. - Nothing.

Comment: Please include a screenshot of what you are trying to click on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graphical interface does not always work well. It seems that it has some problems and bugs! It's better to use nuget console. It's really easy and very fast. Just open it and type like bellow to install the package:

```
Install-package X
```

which X is the name of the package which you can find on the nuget website.

In addition, if you want to uninstall the package, just use 'uninstall' instead of install! The console also let's you do some other things like Migration, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you select Manage Nuget Packages for Solution, if you click on a package to the left, it will offer check boxes to select for the project you'd like to install the package to on the right. This is above the section which says Installed: not installed.

You can also try right clicking the project (the thing just below Solution 'YourSolution') and click Manage Nuget Packages

Finally, you can go to Tools>NuGet Package Manager>Package Manager Console and use Install-Package 'PackageName' to install it as well.